# -undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On the `update` controller action, rails returns following error,

```
undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass
```

Issue is supposed to be in following,

```
def update
  @profile = Profile.find_by(user_id: params[:id])
  if @profile.user == current_user
    @profile.update(profile_params) 
    flash[:info] = "Profile successfully updated" 
  else
```

It doesn't make sense why this is an issue, since I used the exact same code to find profiles in my other actions and they worked perfectly.

Comment: Just because `@profile` is nil. What else is in the code?

Answer (score 2):

`Profile.find_by` is returning `nil` ie: no user was found.
So, when you try `@profile.user`, you are trying to access `user` on a `nil`.

Make sure the profile exists with the `user_id` matching `params[:id]` and that `params[:id]` isn't blank or nil.

A way to get rid of the fatal error would be to check if `@profile` is nil or not before using it:

```
def update
  @profile = Profile.find_by(user_id: params[:id])
  if @profile.present? 
    if @profile.user == current_user
      @profile.update(profile_params) 
      flash[:info] = "Profile successfully updated" 
    else
    end
  else
    # Profile not found
  end
end
```

Or, you could use the bang variation of `find_by`:

`Profile.find_by!`

Which will throw an exception if nothing is found (which you can then rescue from)